# How to install cherrytree on mac os?

Tags: macos

Cherrytree is really a good tool for me, but there is no versions for mac.I have tried all ways I know, but with no lucky.Is there someone who installed cherrytree on macOS successfully?

Comment: Cherrytree can now be installed on MacOS using a MacOS package, homebrew or ports (https://www.giuspen.net/cherrytree/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the Windows version of CherryTree and install it using PlayOnMac. It is a wine implementation and can be used to run a lot of Windows applications.

I hope there will be a native Mac OS X client in the future.

Hope this helps, let me know.

Regards,

Comment: This may be a solution, but a native Mac OS X client is more cooler.And there is also a topic about cherry on Mac OS X:http://www.giuspen.com/topic/cherrytree-on-mac-osx/